# DataContractSerializer metadata export. Related schemas

Tags: import, xsd, schema, datacontractserializer, svcutil.exe

I'm exporting assembly's datacontracts with svcutil.exe. It generates set of xsd files including each other like this:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Reflection" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UBP.Business.Core" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UBP.Core" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UBP.Collection" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
```

It seems to me that this util supposes that all schemas are pulished on server, where each schema could be accessed by specified hyperlink. But if I open each schema separately in  Altova XMLSpy for instance, it will report error that can't find importing schemas. So my question is how to publish generated schemas in order all of them would be visible for each other? Or maybe there are some other options?

Comment: Can you post the svcutil command you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schemas which have been generated are not referenced to each other via hyperlinks, but by relative paths. What you should find is that one of the schema files will be the "main" schema file, and as long as all schema files are present, when you open it in XMLSpy all the relative paths to the other schemas will resolve, and the schema should open fine.

**UPDATE**

My original answer is actually misleading and factually incorrect. There is no relative path defined in the schemas. The files reference each other SOLELY by namespace.

So a type defined in one schema can be used in another by including a reference to the type's namespace.

Forget everything else I said (all the relative path stuff was crap and I wasn't thinking straight when I answered it - apologies for that).

Because you generated these schemas from an assembly which defined lots of interdependent types, the schemas which were generated to contain the XSD equivalents of those types have a high degree of interdependency too, hence all the import statements.

However, by making reference to these namespaces you are able to author new XSD schemas which make use of the types defined in these generated schemas.

The namespace you were asking about (http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/) does not address a resource; rather it enables the re-use of types which are defined under this namespace. You will probably see a corresponding *xmlns* attribute in the root of the schema which will define a prefix to use when referencing types from this namespace.

I hope this is clear.

Comment: No the relative schemas are not resolved! Though they are located in the same directory. I think this is because import directive
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />

doesn't include path to file. It is generated automatically and I don't know how to influence on it

Comment: I think you're not quite right. svcutil generates set of files corresponding to set of namespaces that exist in dll. For example, I have my own class in namespace UBP.Common. It depends ("imports") on classes in namespace System.Data. After exporting metadata we get two files:
System.Data.xsd and UBP.Common.xsd. The last would include import directive <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" /> of namespace defined in first file.
But second file would be not valid xsd file, because import directive doesn't include pointer to file, where this namespace defined!

Comment: Error would be: "Unable to load schema with target namespace http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data"
ps: thanks for staying tuned on my problem ;)

Comment: The thing about the `<import/>` tag - it does contain a `schemaLocation` attribute where you can include a relative path to the imported schema file. However this is an entirely optional attribute. I guess some parsers need to know the path and others can scan the local directory etc looking for the schemas. Can I just confirm you are getting a problem openning the System.Data.xsd schema file in XmlSpy?

Comment: XmlSpy and Visual Studio xsd viewer. Point of my question was about this SchemaLocation attribute. I don't understand why it is not specified, because xml editors can't know what file corresponds this namespace. I'm afraid I have no other solutuion except specifying these schemalocation atributes manually, which is very inconvenient. Because, I can regenerate these file often and number of files could be very huge. So I need to write some third app to do this job...

Comment: In visual studio if you add both schemas into the Schemas Collection (menu Xml -> Schemas) then you can author XML instance documents which can use the types from these schemas. I'm 100% certain that visual studio will resolve the namespaces to the correct schemas for schemas which are placed in the Schemas Collection.